# Variance/Covariance generics in Kotlin

Tags: generics, kotlin, covariance, invariance

There is a sealed-class Result, which is parameterized with two types - success result (T) and error type (R).

It is inheritered by two classes:

a. Success - data class, accepts object T in the constructor

b. Error - data class, accepts object R in the constructor

I need to create a function, which returns Result object. The function has to be created in a way:

- that the result of this function can be assigned to the variables of the following types:

```java
    Result<Number, String>
    Result<Any, String>
```

- that the result of this function can **NOT** be assigned to the variables of the following types:

```java
    Result<Int, CharSequence>
    Result<Int, Any>
```

That is class Result must be covariant on T parameter and invariant on R parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [declaration-site variance](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#declaration-site-variance) provided by Kotlin in the declaration of your Result class.

- `T`     -> By default T is invariant
- `out T` -> makes T covariant
- `in T`  -> makes T contavariant

Example:

```kotlin
sealed class Result<out T, R>(val left: T? = null, val right: R? = null) {
    class Success<T, R>(data: T) : Result<T, R>(left = data)
    class Error<T, R>(data: R) : Result<T, R>(right = data)
}

fun main() {
    val res1 = Result.Success<String, Int>("Test")
    val res2: Result<Any, Int> = res1     // compiles successfully, T is covariant
    val res3: Result<String, Any> = res1  // doesn't compile, R is invariant (Type Mismatch)
}
```

---

A function can return Result as:

```kotlin
fun returnResult(): Result<String, Int> {
    val random = Random.nextBoolean() // random, for demonstration

    retrun if(random) {
        Result.Success("Success Example")
    } else {
        Result.Error(404)
    }
}
```

Comment: How about a separate function?

Comment: @matua function?

Comment: "I need to create a function, which returns Result object." - not simple assigning. I have difficulties with the syntax and if the function has to always parameterized.

Comment: @matua function returns result object? a success or error? how would you wanna set the another generic?

Comment: @matua, like the above?

Comment: Is not returnResult supposed to be also parameterized?

Comment: @matua what do you mean? If you want specific type of result from the funciton then you have specify it, how would you pass different type of results if you make function generic?

Comment: I guess I understand now. Thank you very much!